# I have a problem when transferring the site from the local host to the cPanel host (WordPress site)

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I have transferred the WordPress site from the local host to the cPanel host and actually transferred the site
All actions such as: connecting to a new database, modifying links in database tables and...
And now I can enter the counter management panel, but the problem is something else
According to the console tab in inspect, some files are still trying to be loaded in the previous address, which is local, and this has caused the appearance of the site to interfere.
How do I solve this problem?

[Console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6U4Q.png)

[Disorganized appearance of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/objn2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use a WordPress plugin called `All-in-One WP Migration` this plugin will give you an option to find and replace text in your install. When you are at the section of find and replace, you should find all the instances that the site is referring to the local address and replace them with the live address.

Also, for thing like photos you dont need to include the domain in the `src`

So

```
<img src="localhost/files/imageName.png">
```

Can be written as

```
<img src="/files/imageName.png">
```

And this will save you a small headache in the future!